# Running .app bundled application in non GUI environment causing app to fail at runtime

Tags: macos, .app

I am having a bundled application(.app file) and I am wanting to run this application via ssh session which does not have GUI access. Launching this application in a desktop GUI session, runs the application perfectly. However, on running it on the same machine via ssh session produces an error.

Note: My application does not bring up any GUI window(it' just produces some logs on the terminal), so running it in a non-GUI environment should have worked.

I get the below error when trying to launch the unix exe in the .app bundle( ./Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/Myapp ) on the terminal. I have observed that applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:) gets called and then the below error occurs.

```
+[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:replyErrorCode:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'ClientCallsAuxiliary': Connection interrupted
```

I tried running other bundled applications via ssh, but all seems to produce the same error. Can someone confirm Is running bundled application in a non GUI session not allowed by Apple. If its allowed, how can I solve this?

Even running the .app file using the open command fails to launch the application, although it produces a different error which is consistent across different applications.

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? If so your embedded exe will need to be signed alongside the main app.

Comment: Yes, it is sandboxed and the application is signed.